# What is the Probability of ‘begining’ given ‘the’?

Tags: python, nltk, corpus, tagged-corpus

```
Using an NLTK Conditional Frequency Distribution and the nltk.bigrams function, train a bigram model on the Genesis:

text = nltk.corpus.genesis.words('english-kjv.txt')
bigrams = nltk.bigrams(text)
cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(bigrams)
Answer the following questions

What is the Probability of ‘begining’ given ‘the’?
What is the probability of ‘the’?
```

Note: The probabilities you give as an answer MUST be probabilities computable from this corpus.

Hi, can some help me? this is in the nltk book. When I got it, I got 78% which does not make sense. Im trying to compute this in Python.

Comment: Zero, that's not how "beginning" is spelled :)

Comment: my god genius! .. What about the then? im still getting 78

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is sort of a difference between `probability of 'beginning' intersect 'the'`

```
p('beginning','the')
```

and `probability of 'beginning' given 'the'`:

```
p('beginning'|'the') = p('beginning','the') / p('the')
```

try:

```
from collections import Counter

import nltk

text = nltk.corpus.genesis.words('english-kjv.txt')
bigrams = nltk.bigrams(text)
cfd_bigrams = Counter(bigrams)
cfd_unigrams = Counter(list(text))

print "p('said','unto') =", cfd_bigrams[u'said', u'unto'] / float(sum(cfd_bigrams.values()))

print "p('said'|'unto') =", (cfd_bigrams[u'said', u'unto'] / float(sum(cfd_bigrams.values()))) / cfd_unigrams[u'unto']

print "p('beginning','the') =", cfd_bigrams[u'beginning', u'the']
```

[out]:

```
p('said','unto') = 0.00397649844738
p('said'|'unto') = 6.73982787691e-06
p('beginning','the') = 0
```